# ¿Que significa Undefined array key "name"? no entiendo que significa o como arreglarlo

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

## Pagina web - Venta de videojuegos (carrito de compras)                                --------------- Error en Undefined array key 'name'

Este es una parte del codigo para ver los productos dentro del carrito de compras, lo que no se es porque me aparece ese error porque practicamente no toque la pagina. solamente agrege un nuevo producto.

```
<?php 
        include "config.php";
        session_start();
        
        include "cart.class.php";
        $cart=new Cart();
    ?>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Cart</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <?php include "navbar.php"; ?>
            <div class='container mt-3'>
                <div class='row'>
                    <div class='col-md-12'>
                        <h2 class='text-muted mb-4'>Productos del Carro</h2>
                        <?php if($cart->get_cart_total()>0): ?>
                        <table class='table table-striped table-bordered'>
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th colspan='2' class='text-center'>Producto</th>
                                    <th>Precio</th>
                                    <th>Cantidad</th>
                                    <th>Total</th>
                                    <th>Opcion</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            <?php $items=$cart->get_all_items(); ?>
                            <?php foreach($items as $item): ?>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><img src='images/<?php echo $item["img"];?>' style='height:80px;' ></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $item["name"];?></td>
                                    <td>&#8377; <?php echo $item["price"];?></td>
                                    <td><input type='number' value='<?php echo $item["qty"];?>' class='qty' pid='<?php echo $item["id"]; ?>' min='1'></td>
                                    <td>$<span class='row_total'><?php echo $item["total"];?></span></td>
                                    <td><a href='remove.php?id=<?php echo $item["id"]; ?>' onclick="return confirm('¿Estas seguro?')">ELIMINAR</a></td>
                                </tr>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                            </tbody>
                            <tfoot>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan='3'><a href='Inicio_carro.php' class="btn btn-success">Continuar comprando</a></td>
                                    <th>Total</th>
                                    <th>$<span id='total'><?php echo $cart->get_cart_total();?></span></th>
                                    <td><a href='checkout.php' class='btn btn-info'>Pagar</a></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tfoot>
                        </table>
                        <?php else: ?>
                            <div class='alert alert-warning'>El carro esta vacio</div>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $(".qty").change(function(){
                        update_cart($(this));
                    });
                    $(".qty").keyup(function(){
                        update_cart($(this));
                    });
                    
                    function update_cart(cls){
                        var pid=$(cls).attr("pid");
                        var q=$(cls).val();
                        
                        $.ajax({
                            url:"ajax_update_cart.php",
                            type:"post",
                            data:{id:pid,qty:q},
                            success:function(res){
                                console.log(res);
                                
                                var a=JSON.parse(res);
                                $("#total").text(a.total);
                                $(cls).closest("tr").find(".row_total").text(a.row_total);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Estas son algunas imágenes de ejemplo para ver el error en si como se ve en la página de mi proyecto. Además que este error no me permite hacer el check out de la página por lo que no puedo utilizar el carro de compras por completo.

[image: Página de venta de videojuegos con carrito de compras]

[image: Error en cuestión, no sé cómo solucionarlo]

Answer (score 2):

El error indica que estas intentando acceder a la posicion "name" de un arreglo/objeto, para ser mas especificos, es en esta linea:

`<td><?php echo $item["name"];?></td>`

Al parecer, el objeto no posee esa propiedad o hay un $item que no lo tiene